# lm() - model specification

Tags: r, modeling, interpretation, linear-model, lm

If have multivariate data of 3 response variables and 2 factors (f1 and f2). I can specify an linear model in different ways for this data, however I don't know what the difference between the models is.

Here is a plot of the data: the three variables (columns) and the 2 factors (rows and x-axis).

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = f1, y = y, fill = f1)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(f2~var, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

I could run a linear model like this (1):

```
mod <- lm(y ~ (var-1):f1 + (var-1) + f2, data = df)
summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ (var - 1):f1 + (var - 1) + f2, data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.45565 -0.44102  0.02875  0.40296  2.20795 

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
var1     -0.88371    0.16522  -5.349 2.79e-07 ***
var2     -0.30943    0.16522  -1.873   0.0628 .  
var5     -1.37800    0.16522  -8.340 2.31e-14 ***
f22      -0.09669    0.12714  -0.760   0.4480    
f23       0.04514    0.12043   0.375   0.7083    
var1:f12  0.84551    0.18176   4.652 6.54e-06 ***
var2:f12  1.76148    0.18176   9.691  < 2e-16 ***
var5:f12  1.11851    0.18176   6.154 5.16e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.6692 on 172 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.6491, Adjusted R-squared: 0.6328 
F-statistic: 39.77 on 8 and 172 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I could also run for every variable a separate lm (2). I am aware of the multivariate methods, however I am interested in the response of the three variables separately.

**Questions:**

- What are the differences between both approaches (also for interpretation)?
- When running 3 separate lm should I take this somehow into account? (Multiple testing?) If so, in which way should i do this?
- I noticed that the error in the first model are the same for every variable, might this indicate a problem?

I would interpret the first model like this:

- var is my baseline
- f1 has an effect on all variables (increase compared to baseline),
- however f1 make not difference.
- Is this an appropriate interpretation of the lm()-output?

Thank you for your thoughts!

```
df <- structure(list(var = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "5"), class = "factor"), f1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), f2 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), y = c(-0.04, 
    -1.1, -2.1, -0.98, 0.04, 0.85, -0.96, -1.69, -0.99, 0.06, -1.4, 
    -0.06, 0.68, -0.83, -1.71, -1.04, -1.27, 0.35, 0.04, -2.2, -0.93, 
    -1.21, -1, -1.15, 0.35, -1.01, 0.17, -0.38, -0.97, -0.19, -1.9, 
    -0.08, -1.26, -0.23, -0.17, -1.81, 0.21, -1.81, -1.25, -1.46, 
    -1.67, -0.6, -1.3, -1.28, 0.31, 0.34, -0.33, -1.67, 0.54, 0.7, 
    -1.56, -1.7, -1.36, -0.04, -0.62, 0.86, 0.74, -0.77, 0.1, -0.02, 
    0.25, -0.32, -1.75, -0.72, -0.16, 1.1, -0.32, -1.88, -0.26, -0.02, 
    -0.85, 0.45, 0.51, -0.42, -0.85, -0.28, -0.86, 0.56, -0.33, -1.44, 
    -1.14, 0.17, -0.82, 0.11, -0.93, 1.96, 0.32, -0.18, -0.92, -0.26, 
    -1.56, 1.06, -1.24, -0.46, -0.67, -1.1, 0.42, -0.83, -0.84, -0.17, 
    -1.26, -0.34, -1.13, -0.69, -0.03, 0.67, -0.37, -1.42, 0.64, 
    0.95, -1.03, -1.15, -0.62, 0.19, 0.12, 0.98, 0.43, -0.94, -0.63, 
    -0.45, 1.67, -0.1, -0.08, 1.19, 1.5, 3.66, -0.19, -0.33, 0.93, 
    1.85, 0.28, 1.52, 1.71, 1.33, -0.61, -0.56, 0.45, 2.22, 1.44, 
    0.07, -0.37, 1.46, 0.62, 1.38, 2.35, 3.12, 1.48, 0.35, 0.59, 
    0.98, -0.28, 2.21, 0.34, 0.68, 1.23, -0.4, 1.56, -0.29, -0.12, 
    1.41, -0.21, -0.38, -0.22, -0.74, 1.56, 1.87, 0.45, 0.31, 1.24, 
    1.99, -0.57, -0.7, -0.89, 1.77, 0.09, 3.33, 1.67, 0.43, 1.08, 
    1.1)), .Names = c("var", "f1", "f2", "y"), row.names = c(2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
    18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
    34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 47L, 48L, 
    49L, 50L, 51L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 65L, 
    66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 79L, 80L, 
    81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 94L, 
    96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 
    108L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 
    121L, 122L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
    136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 
    148L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 
    160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 165L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 
    173L, 174L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 
    186L, 187L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 
    200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 
    213L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: No other opinions about this? Or is the question to dumb?

Comment: Not too dumb, but perhaps too long before we get to your questions.  Perhaps adding one or two sentences at the top with the basic idea of the question would help.  Also perhaps putting the data frame at the end would help with readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1 - There are two differences between the two approaches.

First, by estimating it all together you are constraining the variance of the random part to be the same for each of variables 1, 2 and 5.  If you fit the three models separately you will have a different estimate of the variance each time.  A useful thing to do would be to check if this is necessary ie if there really is evidence of this heteroscedasticity (ie variable variance).  Fitting the models simultaneously is more efficient, if it is acceptable to keep the variance the same.

Second, because you do not have an interaction effect between var and f2, a second (perhaps even bigger) difference is that the coefficients for f2 are the same whatever the value of var.  Fitting the models separately would allow those coefficients to change.

Question 2 - absolutely you should.  This is an important decision in your model selection.

Question 3 - this is because you have the same number of observations of each level of var.  Nothing to worry about here.

Question 4 - No, this is not an appropriate interpretation.  Note your model is specified in an unusual way.  You have an interaction effect between f1 and var but no original effect.  This makes it difficult to interpret.  But in any event you cannot make inferences about factors with more than two levels that are explanatory variables by looking at the individual coefficients and their standard errors.  At a minimum, you need to use anova().  And certainly you cannot say that f1 makes no difference.

```
> mod <- lm(y ~ (var-1):f1 + (var-1) + f2, data = df)
> anova(mod)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
var         3 74.246 24.7486  55.268 <2e-16 ***
f2          2  0.330  0.1652   0.369  0.692    
var:f1      3 67.887 22.6289  50.534 <2e-16 ***
Residuals 172 77.020  0.4478                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
> 
> mod2 <- lm(y~var*f1 + f2-1, data=df)
> anova(mod2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
var         3 74.246  24.749  55.2678 < 2.2e-16 ***
f1          1 61.569  61.569 137.4938 < 2.2e-16 ***
f2          2  0.611   0.305   0.6819  0.507011    
var:f1      2  6.038   3.019   6.7415  0.001518 ** 
Residuals 172 77.020   0.448                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! I also restructured to question. Regarding question 2: How would I take this into account? (Multiple testing?)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a model with a limited dependent variable. For example ordered probit, multinomial logit, negative binomial ...etc. The model choice depends on what you are modelling.

Comment: I don't see this as addressing the question about the difference between different models with different choice of explanatory variables.

Comment: @PeterEllis I am suggesting that there are more appropriate models.